# Алгоритм кодирования данных

Tags: java, android

нужно написать приложение на андроид для кодирования и декодирования данных по любому из существующих алгоритмов, кто нибудь может помочь?

Comment: А в чем у вас трудности?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это работа за автора

Answer (score 3):

На вот тебе алгоритм Васи-Пупкина-Джонсона. Проверил - работает.

```
public class Main {

static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    String str="AB";
    System.out.println(str);
    encode(str);
    System.out.println(str);
    dencode(str);
    System.out.println(str);
}
public static void encode(String str) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
    Field f=String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    char[] array=(char[]) f.get(str);
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        array[i]++;
    }
}

public static void dencode(String str) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException{
    Field f=String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    char[] array=(char[]) f.get(str);
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        array[i]--;
    }
}
```

}